# Doctoral program vs Doctorate prgram

Tags: word-usage

If I am referring to a PhD program, is it better to say "Doctoral Program" or "Doctorate Program"?

Answer (score 1):

*Doctoral* would be the better choice. *Doctoral* is an adjective and *doctorate* is a noun. The degree is a "doctorate," and you might call the program itself a "doctorate" (as in "my doctorate took six years"), but a [Google ngram shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=doctoral+program%2Cdoctorate+program&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdoctoral%20program%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdoctorate%20program%3B%2Cc0) that the phrase "doctoral program" is much more common than "doctorate program." This is probably because it's more natural to modify the noun *program* with an adjective. (Though it's not impossible for a noun to act like an adjective and modify another noun—"The Mitchell house," "my car keys," "school transcript.")

Comment: It might be good to add that while "Doctoral Program" is *by far* the *better* choice, "Doctorate Program" is not *wrong*, and is still idiomatic.